# cordova plugin callback to javascript from UI Thread seems to be broken in phonegap 3.3

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I was trying to use the FacebookConnect plugin for phonegap and found that it did not make a callback despite login success, after some digging around and java logging tracing I boiled the problem down to this simple example which resemble the same problem I found with the FacebookConnect plugin ...

this extremely simple test would fail, almost identical to cordova's simpliest plugin dev snippet.

In JS:

```
var cordova = window.cordova || window.Cordova; 
MyTest = { 
    test: function() { 
        console.log("Testing"); 
        alert("Testing"); 
        cordova.exec(function(){ 
                console.log("successful return from test"); 
            }, 
            function(){ 
                console.log("failed return"); 
            }, 'org.apache.cordova.mything.MyTest', 'test', []); 
        } 
    }
```

In Java:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("test")) {
        //Call Back HERE would work
        callbackContext.success(new JSONObject("{}")); 
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Callback here DOES NOT WORK
                //callbackContext.success(new JSONObject());
            };
        });            
    }
}
```

Within the context of this problem:

- "Work" means log message from the javascript "successful return from
  test" is printed out in the log.
- "Does not Work" means log message
  from javascript was not printed (neither success nor fail), the call
  simply gone into the void.

I am new to phonegap and cordova so I do not know if this particular test would work in previous versions.

My test device is a samsung galaxy S3 running android 4.1.2 Compiled this via phonegap 3.3 CLI (the newest I pulled from npm on Dec, 16, 2013 )

Anybody knows/or tested that it this version combination works or it's just my device/OS?

Comment: You can use this plugin https://github.com/studiosoton/faceGap without using native plugin check it

Comment: or u must update plugin like phonegap 3 http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: mohamd, I haven't tried that link, but I've done quite a bit of research and I don't think it is possible to do login to facebook in native apps without a native code plugin. And essentially, the git that you pointed to doesn't look like a a phonegap plugin at all as it's pure javascript based so it looks like just a wrapper around facebook's oauth http calls.

Comment: And to clarify, my problem is not that the plugin does not work systemtically as a plugin. I can install the plugin - no problem at all. It's that something inside the code that makes it logically not working for me. And I traced it down into the Java code for the plugin that I wrote a simple test to reproduce the problem I found with the plugin code.

Comment: Did you figure anything out, @JChow? I'm having much of the same issues, but only on Samsung devices. Won't work from threads at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update this question after I found my problem. It was a really stupid mistake, hopefully it'll help someone else though.

The problem turns out to be the fact that I included both cordova.js and phonegap.js in my project. That happens a lot when you mix phonegap and cordova stuffs ... creating the project with cordova first and then convert it to phonegap yada yada.

Anyway, cordova.js and phonegap.js are essentially the same files. All variables, method names are defined exactly the same way. Apparently when the method calls returned from the Java stuffs, the result exchange from the queue got confused and in my case, the cordova instance of the return variable got the result but not the phonegap instance. Therefore the result returned for my phonegap instance was always empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are returning `true` from the `execute` method in Java. If you return `false`, your success callback will never be invoked.

Comment: Though this wasn't the accepted answer, this should be duly noted by all who end up on this page! Have struggled with this before